# Add an icon to a correct/incorrect answer (css in ionic)

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework

I'm making an quiz app and editing my options at the moment. This is my css for the correct/wrong option

```
.correct {
    background-color:#48D76E;
    color: black;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 0 .5rem 0;
    padding:.6875rem;
    font-size:.875rem;
}

.wrong {
    background-color:#EF473A;
    color: black;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 0 .5rem 0;
    padding:.6875rem;
    font-size:.875rem;
}
```

Is it possible to make an icon appear ( a tick for a correct answer and a cross for an incorrect answer)?

[image]

This is how it look like right now. I'd like it to display a tick if the right answer is chose and a cross when a wrong item is chosen. I'm using ionic framework to build this app. Can anyone advise me with this matter? I'd like to use these icons http://ionicons.com/

Comment: Yes, this is very possible but what have you tried so far? Do you know how to use ionicons? If not then I suggest you read the documentation and learn how to use them before attempting to apply them to your existing projects.

Comment: @NewToJS I tried adding divisions without success, I also tried adding a before class in css, also without success. Can you please sum up what steps I need to do?

Comment: If you want the ionicon to display to the right of the answer I would dynamically create a div inside of the answers with  style property set to float right and apply the icon class required for that answer. Either that or have an empty span/div in the answer and just apply a class upon validation/confirmation whatever you have in place for checking answers.

Comment: Thanks, that puts me on the right track

Comment: Happy to help, If you have problems after making an attempt feel free to return and explain the issue you are having. I wish you luck with your development.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Font Awesome* for icons, they have LOTS of icons, and use CSS, so you can make them bigger or smaller.

Here's their website **[Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/)**, from there, you can look at all their icons to see which ones you like, but we want *[fa-check](http://fontawesome.io/icon/check/)* and *[fa-times](http://fontawesome.io/icon/times/)*, so I'll give an example code to show you what I mean:

```html
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Font Awesome Demo</title>
      <!--This is how your webpage will be able to use Font Awesome-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      <!--Use fa-3x to make the icon larger, 
      you can also use fa-1x, 2x, 4x, and 5x to control the size of your icon-->
      <i class="fa fa-times fa-3x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-check fa-3x"></i>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Hope that helped you with icons!

Answer (score 1):

This [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harishkommuri/hvddm5cc/1/) may help you.

Check by click right and wrong buttons in Fiddle.

Use following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function right() {
     document.getElementsByClassName('result-right')[0].classList.add('correct');
     document.getElementsByClassName('result-wrong')[0].classList.remove('wrong');
     document.querySelectorAll('.result-right span')[0].classList.add('ion-checkmark-circled');
     document.querySelectorAll('.result-wrong span')[0].classList.remove('ion-close-circled');
   }

   function wrong() {
     document.getElementsByClassName('result-wrong')[0].classList.add('wrong');
     document.getElementsByClassName('result-right')[0].classList.remove('correct');
     document.querySelectorAll('.result-wrong span')[0].classList.add('ion-close-circled');
     document.querySelectorAll('.result-right span')[0].classList.remove('ion-checkmark-circled');
   }

</script>
<div class="result-right">
  A) TRUE <span class=""></span>
</div>
<div class="result-wrong">
  B) FALSE <span class=""></span>
</div>
<button class="button ans-right" onclick="right()">
  Right
</button>
<button class="button ans-wrong" onclick="wrong()">
  Wrong
</button>
```